# Simplifying the expression $(1+\sqrt[4]3)/(1-\sqrt[4]3)+1/(1+\sqrt[4]3)+2/(1+\sqrt{3})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Can anyone give provide me some help to simplify this expression?

The three denominators are pretty much different, and I can't find a common denominator.

$$\frac{1+\sqrt[4]3}{1-\sqrt[4]3}+\frac1{1+\sqrt[4]3}+\frac2{1+\sqrt{3}}$$

The calculator said it's equal to $-2$, but I don't get how a complicated expression like this would be equal to $-2$.

Comment: You can use the brackets to make the fourth root, instead of `3^(1/4)` write `3^{1/4}`, alternatively, you can use `\sqrt[4]{3}` to get $\sqrt[4]{3}$.

Comment: Still not a polynomial.

Comment: The result is not $-2$, you sure you copied the question correctly?  Here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2B3%5E.25%29%2F%281-3%5E.25%29%2B1%2F%281%2B3%5E.25%29%2B2%2F%281%2B3%5E.25%29

Comment: @DannyCheuk:  your input has the last one with a fourth root instead of square root.  [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2B3^.25%29%2F%281-3^.25%29%2B1%2F%281%2B3^.25%29%2B2%2F%281%2B3^.5%29) is the one asked for.  Still a ways from $-2$

Comment: You're indeed correct, thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a method.

This is not a polynomial. However ... the basic rules for combining fractions apply even in cases with roots in. You put the expression over a common denominator. Note that for any $x$ whatsoever $(1+x)(1-x)=1-x^2$.

Use this to help you to add the first pair of fractions and simplify it.

You then have two fractions to add, and you will be able to use the same identity again.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $(1-a)(1+a)=1-a^2$ and hence $(1-a)(1+a)(1+a^2)=1-a^4$

Answer (score 2):

Putting  $\sqrt[4]3=x$

$$\frac{1+\sqrt[4]3}{1-\sqrt[4]3}+\frac1{1+\sqrt[4]3}+\frac2{1+\sqrt{3}}$$

$$=\frac{1+x}{1-x}+\frac1{1+x}+\frac2{1+x^2}$$

$$=\frac x{1-x}+\frac1{1-x}+\frac1{1+x}+\frac2{1+x^2}$$

$$=\frac x{1-x}+\frac{1+x+1-x}{(1-x)(1+x)}+\frac2{1+x^2}$$

$$=\frac x{1-x}+2\left(\frac1{1-x^2}+\frac1{1+x^2}\right)$$

$$=\frac x{1-x}+2\left(\frac{1+x^2+1-x^2}{(1-x^2)(1+x^2)}\right)$$

$$=\frac x{1-x}+\frac4{1-x^4}$$

Now $x^4=3$ as  $\sqrt[4]3=x$

Comment: I'm having trouble going from the second line to the third.

Comment: Shouldn't the third line be $$\frac{(1+x)^2+1-x}{(1-x)(1+x)}+\frac2{1+x^2}$$

Comment: @TheChaz2.0, sorry for the mistake.Please have a look into the edited version

Comment: @chubakueno,  sorry for the mistake.Please have a look into the edited version.Thanks for your observation

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the first and second term by their conjugate respectively. Add the terms.

You will get

$\frac{2 + \sqrt[4]{3}+\sqrt{3}}{1-\sqrt{3}}$
Now multiply both the bottom and top by the conjugate of the denominator. And do the same for the third term.